# .show () jumping issue between divs

Tags: jquery

Im trying to make my own Mega Menu for a site.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#homeDropdown').hide();
    $('#aboutDropdown').hide();

    $("#homeBtn").hover(function () {

    $(".btnDropdown").hide();
    $("#homeDropdown").show("slow");

});


    $("#aboutBtn").hover(function () {
    $(".btnDropdown").hide();
    $("#aboutDropdown").show("slow");
});

$('#homeDropdown').hover(function () {
$("#homeDropdown").show();

}); 

$('#aboutDropdown').hover(function () {
$("#aboutDropdown").show();

}); 
});

</script>
```

I'm using the following but it seems to shutter when you go over the ".dropdowns" am i going about this the right way?

http://jsfiddle.net/ma9ic/9Lksq/

Comment: Please, indent your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it smoother I just added some check, to not close the window that we want to open anyway.

Also, I added the animation to hide, it's easier on the eye when the item doesn't just disapear.

This would make it smoother :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#homeDropdown').hide();
    $('#aboutDropdown').hide();

    $("#homeBtn").hover(function () {
        $(".btnDropdown").not("#homeDropdown").hide("fast");
        $("#homeDropdown").show("slow");
    });


    $("#aboutBtn").hover(function () {
        $(".btnDropdown").not("#aboutDropdown").hide("fast");
        $("#aboutDropdown").show("slow");
    });

    $('#homeDropdown').hover(function () {    
        $("#homeDropdown").show();
    }); 

    $('#aboutDropdown').hover(function () {
        $("#aboutDropdown").show();
    }); 
});
```

You can test it here : http://jsfiddle.net/9Lksq/2/